# How to change the PI of the existing huge table in Teradata ?

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

We have a huge table in Teradata holding the transnational data sizing approximately 13 TB.
As a typical old Data Warehouse enhancement case, we have now found that the PI selection made in the past for this table is not the best. And due to this, we are facing lots of performance issues with the SQL's pulling data from this table.

So the very first idea that we wanted to implement is to load the data in temp table, alter the PI of the existing table or create a new table with new PI and load the data from temp table to new \ altered table.

But the challenge here is the table is live and this solution will not be the best due the size of the data movement. Also, other way we thought about delta load (to new table) - delta delete (from main table). But this also can not be the best workaround as the table is live and it will involve too much of efforts in data movement as well as in matching the row counts in source and target table.

I need your ideas on this scenario, how can I change the PI of this table by making small efforts without any system downtime.

Comment: How is the table loaded, daily/hourly/near real time? Is the source table partitioned? Is there any compression, MVC/BLC? Insert/Select into a new table needs at least additional 13 TB plus 13 TB spool (or more when compressed).

Comment: For now the table is loaded on daily basis. But we have plans to load it on every 30 mins. interval. (fyi, we get feed from OOG ). And yes, table is compressed. I am not sure what MVC/BLC means ... Table is also partitioned on load txn date on day interval.

Comment: MVC/BLC is Multi Value & Block Level Compression. Assuming end users access using Access Lock you got almost a full day to copy the data to the new table, if it's loaded daily. You should test and Insert/Select a few partitions into the new table and check spool usage/run time from QueryLog. Based on that you can decide wether to run a single huge Insert/Select or multiple copying n partitions each. Insert/Select in an empty table/partition has no journaling overhead (when the Select is based on the target partitioning).

Comment: I am newbie to Teradata. I believe the compression in table is a multi value. Because when I see the definition of the table, I can see COMPRESS (list of values ...). And loading partition by partition you mean using the where clause filter on partitioned column right ? So in my case days or months(Load txn time). But we are looking for some other alternative like without creating a copy of data, without any downtime, would it be possible to change the PI ?

Comment: There aren't any shortcuts. You can't re-define the PI of a table with data in it.  You have to move the data to a new table.  BTW, you said you're new to Teradata.  In that case, are you sure that skew is the problem?

Comment: Other alternatives to try that are more band-aids than organ replacement are single table join indexes with the desired PI or (possibly less ideal) a hash index with the desired PI. The single table join index could be a sparse join index that limits the number of `load_txn_date` partitions it will cover. You could implement multiple join indexes that may help cover multiple scenarios where your existing PI causes pain. However, join indexes will come at a cost in terms of space and ETL overhead. Rebuilding the table may be the best solution instead of kicking the can down the road further.

Comment: Dump/load into a new empty table with a new PI, then catch up the records based on the dateAdded timestamp. Switch access between tables using a view, which will allow you to synchronize both objects any way you prefer. Every new record is added to the new table on trigger, so you won't be losing it, and as soon as you close the gap, recompile the view, thus making end-users hit the new table.

Comment: @Andrew. Thanks & yes, the PI is causing the issue. Its not the most unique columns and not much used in the joins. Moreover, the PI is a composite PI which also includes the load txn timestamp columns. Now getting hand on this TD monster table since last 1.5 yrs :)

Comment: @RobPaller, thanks for the alternate solution. Definitely we will try to build a new table .. but we will keep Plan B ready :)

Comment: @access_granted, you are saying to do the INS .. SEL based on the record CREATE DATE. I mean DELTA or say bucket load. Right ? And you are also saying about trigger ? so creating trigger on live table ? Wont it causes any performance issues ? never tried trigger on TD tables ... hope you have read my question & know my pain point. Table is 13 TB having partitions ...

Comment: I think access_granted may be suggesting partial dumps to a flat file, perhaps using the partitioned column to pull data efficiently and load to the new table. If you use Teradata Parallel Transport you may be able to do it without landed the data to disk. I know I have moved data between systems without landing to disk, I haven’t tried looping it back to the same system yet. If you have to land to disk, you may be able do it in chunks to avoid asking for 10-15TB of space on your server.